# Having python display errors in window

Tags: python

In any python code I write that gets an error, it will show the error but the window will disappear right away and i can't see the error. It makes fixing codes really difficult. can anyone help me? (i have python 2.7 installed and with my programs i type them in notepad and save them as a .py file)

Comment: What IDE are you using? How are you running your program?

Comment: @yoyo311 Obviously he's simply double-clicking the .py file.

Comment: You could try using an IDE like pyscripter or spyder, which would also give you the benefit of syntax-highlighting etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your main code body in an exception handler and if an exception occurs, display it and wait for user input:

```
import traceback

try:
    <main code>
except Exception:
    print traceback.format_exc()
    raw_input("Press return to exit")
```

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt and `cd` to the directory where your `.py` file is and type the name of the file there to run it.

Comment: This only works if your computer recognizes .py as python file. If not you have to type `python` file.py, and if this does not work you first have to set the python.exe location in PATH environment variable (assuming windows).

Comment: @yoyo311 Of course. But I'm quite certain his computer recognizes .py files from the description of the problem.

Comment: I can run the code fine, it just won't display any errors the code gets. it will show the error for a split second and the window will close.

Comment: @mdlp0716 this will fix that. Try it.

Comment: @Blorgbeard how exactly do you do this? im not exactly sure what it means to cd to the directory where my .py files are

Comment: OK, well if you're not familiar with cmd.exe it might be easier to use something like [PyScripter](https://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/) instead of notepad. Then you can just hit ctrl+f9 to run your code and it will show you any errors nicely and highlight the error line, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Open a command prompt, `cd` into the directory where the file is, and then do the following:**

Redirect the standard error to a file as such:

```
python myscript.py > errorlog.txt 2>&1
```

**Test:**

`myscript.py`:

```
import time

time.sleep(2)

raise ValueError ('This should be redirected')
```

**Running**:

```
$ python myscript.py > errorlog.txt 2>&1
$
```

`errorlog.txt` after running:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 5, in <module>
    raise ValueError ('This should be redirected')
ValueError: This should be redirected
```

Comment: If OP was running his script from the command-line, he wouldn't have a problem anyway. He's double-clicking it in windows, so he can't redirect stderr

Comment: Edited, to fit, added an information to the top like @ooga

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using an IDE instead of notepad. It will make writing and debugging code much easier for you.

Here's a screenshot of [pyscripter](https://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/) showing me exactly which line caused my error.

You can see how much easier it is to see what's going on.

[image: debugging python screenshot]